# Make a div in css fill to the end of the page with Top Bar

Tags: html, css, orientation, fill

I have a probably very easy question in CSS
I have Elements like this:

```
+-----------+--+
|    A      | B|
+--+--------+--+
|  |           |
|  |           |
| C|     D     |
|  |           |
|  |           |
|  |           |
+--------------+
```

I want C and D to fill the entire page, except the headline. I have tried various things and already found a few questions like these, but none with a satisfying answer. When I set them to 100%, they use too much space. I could make all Elements absolute and work with paddings and z-index, but that is not how I want it to be. I did it for Element A and B. I do not like this, but it will work for these. But there must be a way to achieve the following:

A: in the top left corner, fixed height, variable length that reaches to Element B

B: in the top right corner, fixed height, fixed width

C: left side, directly below Element A, fixed width, fills space till the end (height)

D: to the right of C, underneath A, fills the space to the bottom and to the right

This is precisely how I would like it to be. Can anybody help?

For now this is my code:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="pictures/logo1.png" alt="Logo von VIA e.V." width="171" height="100">
    </div>

    <div id="logout">
        Hallo
    </div>

    <div id="menu">
        Menu
    </div>

    <div id="mainWindow">
        mainWindow
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
*
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#logo
{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    z-index: -1;
}

#logout
{
    width: 190px;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #BFBFBF;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    padding: 5px;
}

#menu
{
    width: 161;
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 5px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    float: left;
}

#mainWindow
{
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
}
```

Comment: have you tried bootstrap grid system?  makes this disgustingly easy...http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: Check out my codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azBebE.  Use floats instead of absolute positioning

Comment: If you know the height of the top bar, you could use `calc()`. For example, if the top bar's height is 100px, you can do `height:calc(100% - 100px)` for the C and D divs.